# Fix error when assigning a list of values to dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas

When I execute this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame creation
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]}, index=[0, 1, 2])

# Assuming idx is a valid index in df, for example:
idx = 1

# Store the list as a single value in the DataFrame
df.loc[idx, 'SHAP'] = [1, 2]

print(df)
```

I get the error: `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable` how do I fix this? I am using pandas version `2.1.4`

Comment: You can't assign list as items. Pandas is not designed to use objects. One workaround: `df['SHAP'] = None ; df.at[idx, 'SHAP'] = [1, 2]`